# DS.Model url not working in ember.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm very, very, very new to Ember :-)

I have a DS.Model where I want to force the extension with .json, for retrieving the data from a Rails Server.

The url from the Server is working, and for I can see in the browser's debugger, the url is not what it's specified in the DS.model url

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();

App.store = DS.Store.create({
 adapter:  DS.RESTAdapter.create({url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000'}),
revision: 8
});


App.Expedient = DS.Model.extend({
  url: 'expedients/%@.json',
  procedencia: DS.attr('string'),
  interessat_nom: DS.attr('string'),
  data_signatura_provisional: DS.attr('date')
});
```

Fetch the expedient manually:

```
var model2 = App.store.find(App.Expedient, 125000);
```

Output console:

```
OPTIONS http://127.0.0.1:3000/expedients/125000 404 (Not Found)
```

I would like to be this url like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/expedients/125000.json
```

Also I've tried to really change the DS.Model url with another different name like this:

```
App.Expedient.reopenClass({
 url: 'mockurl/%@.json'
});
```

But the browser's console has the same 'url' as before, I don't know why Ember-Data is not getting the model's url.

thanks!

regards,

ps. I'm aware of the Access-Control-Allow-Origin CORS problem when testing Ajax from two origins

Answer (score 5, accepted):

github isn't working right now, for some reason, so I can't look at the source for ember, but I think you can do something like this:

```
var adapter = DS.RestAdapter.extend({
  buildURL: function(record, suffix) {
    var s = this._super(record, suffix);
    return s + ".json";
  })
});
```

You'll need to plug this your store instead of the default rest adapter.

Comment: It's not working, maybe (sure) my code is wrong, I've edited the question with the new code

Comment: i'll take a look once github is back up.

Comment: @mongeta I updated my code, try that. If you take a look at the ember data rest adapter for buildURL (https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L366) you can see what's going on. Maybe try seeing what the return value for `this._super(record, suffix);` is. Is it calling the parent method instead? Notice I changed it to extend, instead of create.

Comment: same problem... I'll try to read the source code and see... thanks!

Comment: is the method being called?

Comment: It's not automatic when I create the Store with App.store = DS.Store.create... .

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance on ember and ember-data, but this method is not suposed to be invoked automatically when you assign/create and Adapter and assign it to a Store? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I just tried this with my RESTAdapter subclass and it's working:

```
 App.WORESTAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    ...
    buildURL: function(record, suffix){
       return this._super(record, suffix) + ".json";
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with a rails back end would it be easier to adapt your API to the same conventions Ember.data expects? so in your `expedientsController#show` action:

```
def show
  @expedient = Expedient.find(params[:id])
  render json: @expedient
end
```

As long as your controller is returning the JSON structure Ember expects it should map to your `DS.Model` see: [this ember guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/).

Comment: This will work, but it assumes that all requests should return JSON. So if you have an HTML admin tool you want the request to be the correct type so you can format dynamically, rather than force the type on the server side. For a Rails api, appending .json in the adapter seems to be the best solution until Ember has some cleaner options.